# Why radioButtonGroup doesn't set its numRadioButons instantaneously?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

Here is my code:

```
            var x : int = 50;
            var group : RadioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup();
            for (var i : int = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                var rb : RadioButton = new RadioButton();
                rb.id = i.toString();
                rb.group = group;
                rb.label = i.toString();
                rb.x = x;
                x += 40;
                cnv_subContent.addElement(rb);//a BorderContainer
            }
            Alert.show(group.numRadioButtons.toString());
```

when i run the application, it shows me "0". Why this?

Comment: what do you see when you debug your application? Are the labels added to the group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the [flex component lifecycle](http://bit.ly/ctxMG8).  When a RadioButton is assigned a group, it doesn't actually get added until its commitProperties runs a frame later.

To get the correct group.numRadioButtons, you'll have to do things asynchronously.  Something interesting is spark.components.RadioButtonGroup actually dispatches an undocumented "numRadioButtonsChanged" event whenever radio buttons are added or removed.  It works but of course being undocumented use at your own risk.